# Oracle instance in docker

Tags: database, oracle, docker

I need help on how to proceed with working with a database in docker. I have Oracle 11g used in my application, need to see how it can be installed in docker and start developing and auto deploy.

Comment: Find Oracle 11g EE on Docker [here](https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-ee-11g)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on how to build an Oracle DB image can be found [here](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md).

Alternatively, you could download the pre-built image from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition) and use that as your starting point (note that the image is for version 12c though).